# Why is this memory referencing segfault?

Tags: c, memory-management

```
double fun(int i)
{
 volatile double d[1] = {3.14};
 volatile long int a[2];
 a[i] = 1073741824;
 return d[0];
}
```

fun(0) ➙ 3.14

fun(1) ➙ 3.14

fun(2) ➙ 3.1399998664856

fun(3) ➙ 2.00000061035156

fun(4) ➙ 3.14, then segmentation fault

can someone explain to me whats going on in this example and why segfault dont show up when calling func(2)?
and why return value not always 3.14?

Comment: You call `fun(2)`, `fun(3)` and `fun(4)`, where the size of `a` is only 2 entries, what did you expect???

Comment: @barakmanos; Post an answer.

Comment: @barakmanos as i mentioned i expect segfault to come at fun(2) and according to this it comes only at 4.

Comment: @user4464936  if you want it arrive at fun(2) you can use the lib efence http://linux.die.net/man/3/efence

Comment: Undefined behavior is behavior which is undefined.

Comment: This is multi-duped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You declare an array of 2 entries:

```
volatile long int a[2];
```

You then access this array with an index:

```
a[i] = 1073741824;
```

Since array-indexing in C starts at 0, any index larger than 1 would yield undefined behavior.

In your program, you are calling the function with indexes `i=2`, `i=3` and `i=4`.

Each one of these function calls independently yields undefined behavior.

Undefined behavior means that **anything** can happen.

The fact that you're experiencing a segmentation fault only upon `fun(4)` is a mere coincidence.

---

## Supplemental:

**Disclaimer**: the following analysis does not imply that the same behavior is to be expected on every platform, or even on every execution; it is merely in order to explain the "odd" return-values observed.

- The 4-byte hexadecimal value of `1073741824` is `0x40000000`
- The 8-byte hexadecimal value of `3.14` is `0x40091EB851EB851F` (in compliance with IEEE 754)
- By writing `0x40000000` into `a[2]`, you have overridden the 4 least significant bytes in the 8-byte value of `d[0]` (without causing a segmentation fault), thus changing it from `0x40091EB851EB851F` to `0x40091EB840000000`, which stands for the (IEEE 754) floating-point value of `3.1399998664856`
- By writing `0x40000000` into `a[3]`, you have overridden the 4 most significant bytes in the 8-byte value of `d[0]` (without causing a segmentation fault), thus changing it from `0x40091EB851EB851F` to `0x4000000051EB851F`, which stands for the (IEEE 754) floating-point value of `2.0000006103516`

Comment: @user4464936: See supplemental.

Comment: Why did you not search for dups?  This 'array bounds exceeded but no segfault'  is posted every other day:(

Comment: @MartinJames: Dunno... At first, I just wrote a comment. Then, some other user suggested to make it an answer. Then, I noticed I could explain to OP the "odd" return-values that he or she were observing (with a **big disclaimer** that it's not there in order to explain the general undefined behaviour). I suppose that posting an answer to a duplicate question couldn't do much harm. If it's a complete duplicate, then crown-wisdom will ultimately get it closed. If it's partially duplicate (or not at all), then it will eventually remain as a legitimate post.